# Setting mssql on php7.0 on a linux machine

Tags: php, sql-server, centos7

I am setting php 7.0.33 on a linux machine running centOs 7.
I've installed the php by getting the epel and remi repos:

`rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.nch.rpm`

&

`rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm`

Then installed it `yum install php70w`

Now I need to query mssql with my php, so as usually I also installed mssql and sqlsrv:

```
yum install php70w-mssql
yum install php70w-sqlsrv
yum install php70w-pdo-sqlsrv
```

But for some reason, instead of the usual modules: `pdo_sqlsrv.so` and `sqlsrv.so` it downloaded a `pdo_dblib.so` which does not support my `sqlsrv_connect`...

Have there been a update in the remi repository or something? And how can I still get my sqlsrv libraries?

Thank you

Comment: ^ There's no accepted answer, but there are a bunch of highly upvoted answers with some good explanations and examples.

Comment: Oh thx! My bad, I havent seen that question